# Is there a way to add multiple nodes with the .net neo4j.client?

Tags: .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

Is it possible to multiple nodes in one request with the .net neo4j.client?

We have less than 100000 nodes that we would like to insert into neo4j, and we also want to be able to to this multiple times. Is there a way to insert this in batches, without using the batch API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Unwind`, so something like this:

```
var nodes = new List<MyNode>();
/* Fill nodes */

var query = client.Cypher
                .Unwind(nodes, "node")
                .Create("(n:MyNode)")
                .Set("n = node")
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I think you'll need to split the `nodes` and probably look at batching the number you do at a time. I can't remember the speed I got from this, but by all means give it a go with all 100,000...

In my tests:
10,000 ~ 3.8s (first time), about 1.6s second time...

Comment: I will definitely try this. It took way to long when writing nodes one by one, I tried to do it in parallel and got it down some... but stil only a couple of hundred writes per second. So I hope your solution works. Will try it first thing Monday morning.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it with edges? I get some weird error when trying to unwind this to also create relations `client.Cypher
                                .Unwind(x, "idMap")
                                .Match("n1", "n2")
                                .Where("n1.Id=idMap.Owner")
                                .AndWhere("n2.Id=idMap.User")
                                .Create(sprintf "n1-[:%s]->n2" (relationTypeToString relationType))
                                .ExecuteWithoutResults()`